# 4th order method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am asked to solve a ODE using the 4th order Runge-Kutta method, and then given the analytical answer, 'show the method is 4th order numerically' .

What does the question 'show the method is 4th order numerically' mean?

Thanks

Comment: Loosely speaking, it means that if the true solution to your differential equation is a fourth order polynomial, then RK4 gives you the correct answer, but not for a fifth-degree polynomial. Alternatively, the error term is (bounded by) a fifth power of the step size.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks. I will be back later to post the question as I'm not sure how I would show that